# Why vue can't detect the change of "vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue"?

Tags: vue.js, frontend

When I read the guide from Vue, it said:

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`.

But when I read the code, I found this:

```
var Observer = function Observer(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.dep = new Dep();
    this.vmCount = 0;
    def(value, '__ob__', this);
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        var augment = hasProto ? protoAugment : copyAugment;
        augment(value, arrayMethods, arrayKeys);
        this.observeArray(value);
    } else {
        this.walk(value);
    }
};
```

if I change to this:

```
var Observer = function Observer(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.dep = new Dep();
    this.vmCount = 0;
    def(value, '__ob__', this);
    this.walk(value);
};
```

The change of `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue` can be detected if `indexOfItem` less than `array.length - 1`.

So why not?

Answer (score 1):

Caveat I am not completely sure about how all of Vue's reactivity works.

However, I believe the answer lies in the fact that because of the need to support >=IE9 Vue uses [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). This allows you to create getters and setters for an object's properties **that are known beforehand**. This differs from Proxies where you can set traps for setting a new unknown property (Though a cursory examination of the code makes me think Vue does uses Proxies where it can and then falls back on defineProperty where it can't).

What this means for arrays is that similar to objects you cannot set arbitrary properties that Vue doesn't know about beforehand. `vm.list.newProperty='foo'` or `vm.list[5]='foo'`. Both of these are performing equivalent actions since the brackets are an alternate form of property access.

Now, addressing the fact that when you change the code it works for arrays. The problem is it only works for, like you mentioned, `length-1`. This means that adding new values to the array do not become reactive unless you add them using something like push. Which leads us back to you can't use brackets to set values on an array.

Also, for the developers' sake (and possibly performance) it is much better that you disallow all access using brackets then say

> Using brackets to access arrays works only for those values in the array that are initialized or are set later using an array method. Attempting to set an array value using bracket notation will not work if it is outside the list current list.

Or another way if we make your change to the code

```
data:{
  list:[1,2,3]
}
//in your methods
list[0]=0//works
list[3]=4//doesn't work
list.push(4)
list[3]=5//now works
```

I think it becomes pretty obvious how error prone this could get if the developer had to keep track of the length of each array in his head and only use accessors less than that.

Hopefully this explanation makes sense. For those who are curious about the future adoption of Proxies which could make this situation obsolete check this [answer](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3020) by Evan You the creator of Vue.